# Send email after user registration in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send me a  email after a user register with his information but I get this error:

```
SyntaxError (/mailers/user_mailer.rb:6: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
C:/Sites/dc/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected $end
    mail(to: email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
 ^):
  app/models/user.rb:24:in `enviar_mail_activado'
```

I have this class mailer

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "xx@gmail.com"

  def welcome_message()
    mail(to: 'xxx@example.com', subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

Then in my User model an after_save filter and this  method:

```
def enviar_mail_activado
    UserMailer.welcome_message().deliver    
end
```

And my environment.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :domain         => 'mail.google.com',
  :port           => 587,
  :user_name      => 'xxx@gmail.com',
  :password       => 'xxxxx',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Why i have that error? Its show me in the log not at the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you're using some non-ascii character in the user_mailer.rb.

Add `# encoding: utf-8` to the beginning of the file.

Comment: I found that but its seems that I put it in the wrong file, thanks a lot